# SQL - Return previous record details as column by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a list of records showing changes in location and dates to display as one row for each record showing previous location. 
Basically a query to take data like:

[image]

And display it like:

[image]

I tried using `lag`, but it mixes up some of the records. Would anyone be able suggest a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Self join, or group by. Add one more Joe row, and one single Alice row. Then adjust the result!

Comment: Self join + `where A.date > b.date` is enough.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? if 2012 or over you can use lag and lead functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(ID INT ,NAME VARCHAR(20), LOCATIONDATE DATETIME, REASON VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE 
(ID,NAME, LOCATIONDATE, REASON)
VALUES
( 1,'abc',CAST('2016/01/01' AS SMALLDATETIME),'move'),
( 2,'def',CAST('2016/02/01' AS SMALLDATETIME),'move'),
( 1,'abc',CAST('2016/06/01' AS SMALLDATETIME),'move'),
( 2,'def',CAST('2016/07/01' AS SMALLDATETIME),'move'),
( 1,'abc',CAST('2016/08/01' AS SMALLDATETIME),'move'),
( 3,'ghi',CAST('2016/08/01' AS SMALLDATETIME),'move')

select  s.*
        ,t1.*
from
(
select  t.*,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by  locationdate desc) rn
from    @table t
) s
left join
(
select  t.*,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by  locationdate desc) rn
from    @table t
) t1
on t1.id = s.id and t1.rn = s.rn + 1
```

Comment: If you only ever have 2 moves then a simple join as suggested previously will do it. if you have more then a row_number method will probably be better. You may need to adjust the join to deal with how you wish to show ids who have only one entry

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,a.location as currentLocation,a.locationdatedate as currrentLocate,b.location as preLocation,b.locationdatedate as prevLocate,a.changereason 
FROM test as a
JOIN test as b ON a.name = b.name 
where a.locationdatedate > b.locationdatedate
group by a.name
```

Comment: Invalid group by. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 0):

Pleas try this one. it works here

```
SELECT l.id,
    ,l.name
    ,l.location as currentLocation
    ,l.locationdatedate as currrentLocate
    ,r.location as preLocation
    ,r.locationdatedate as prevLocate
    ,r.changereason 
FROM tableName AS l inner join 
tableName AS r ON r.id=l.id 
WHERE l.locationdatedate !=r.locationdatedate AND l.locationdatedate >   r.locationdatedate
```